# How to make videos horizontally aligned in HTML 5

Tags: html, video, youtube

I am wondering how to make videos horizontally aligned so that they are side to side on the page. Here is what I'm trying to achieve richtechservice.weebly.com/intro.html . As you can see they are centered and put side to side. How do i do that?

```html
<hr>

<div>
 
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/czpFFcw6Yfk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r2u2FS-gWmo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  

<div>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MvjlUrWo1KQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F8qDtzlkFws" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This question is overly broad and I am voting to close. If you have code already written and need help debugging it to get the desired behavior, then help can be offered here on SO.

Comment: your "link" doesn't work.

Comment: Your link does work and the snippet shows what you want to achieve. Is the problem resolved?

Answer (score -1):

Put them inside a `<TABLE>`, all in the same `<TR>`

Probably need to put each in its own `<IFRAME>`

[EDIT]

```
<table> <tr>
<td><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/czpFFcw6Yfk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></td>
<td><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r2u2FS-gWmo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </td>
<td><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MvjlUrWo1KQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></td>
</tr></table>
```